# error in compiling flex program with g++

Tags: c++, token, lex, flex-lexer

Here is my simple lex file with main function inside it . 
I want to compile it using g++ .

```
%{
    #include <iostream>
    %}
    %%
    [ \t] ;
    [0-9]+\.[0-9]+ { cout << "Found a floating-point number:" << yytext << endl; }
    [0-9]+  { cout << "Found an integer:" << yytext << endl; }
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+ { cout << "Found a string: " << yytext << endl; }
    %%
    main() {
        // lex through the input:
        yylex();
    }
```

I run following commands on my terminal 
lex ex1.l

g++ lex.yy.c -lfl -o scanner

i get following error

[image: error]

Comment: Please get rid of that bandwidth-wasting image and post the *text* of the compile errors.

Answer (score 1):

`cout` lives in the `std` namespace. You need to refer to it as

```
std::cout
```

The same applies to `endl`.

Note, you can say

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

somewhere before using `cout` and `endl` names. You should be careful that there is no potential for name clashes when doing this. Use it in limited scopes, and not in header files.